# Get URL of web page from Bot Framework

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

Hy.

My chatbot is hosted on a website http://www.abs.com

I wish I could in a "hello world" get the url: to have a “Hello world www.abc.com "
I tried to use the 'HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri' and 'activity.ServiceUrl' methods but it didn't work.

In a second step i tried a new method by putting the code in my default.html

```
<script>
    var urlref = window.location.href;

    BotChat.App({
        directLine: { secret: "{directline_secret}" },
        user: { id: 'You', referrer: urlref},
        bot: { id: '{bot_id}' },
        resize: 'detect'
    }, document.getElementById("bot"));
</script>
```

and in my BasicBotDialog.cs:

```
  if (activity.From.Properties["referrer"] != null)
  {
      var urlref= message.From.Properties["referrer"].ToString();
      await context.PostAsync("hy the page of the chatbot is" + urlref);
  }
```

but it doesn't work. Anyone have an idea.

PS: I use C# as a programming language and SDK 3.0.

Comment: What do you mean get the URL ? what URL ? Can you describe what the user should say and what the bot should  reply in the desired scenario please

Comment: Let me clarify what I think you mean. You have a bot hosted on some website. You would like the bot to tell the user the url of the webpage they're on?

Comment: Were you able to get this working with my answer? If so, please "accept" and upvote it so others can quickly find the answer and I can clear this from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `ServiceUrl` is only going to get the URL of the Channel. If you want the actual URL of the site the user is on, I'd suggest something like [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/samples/04.api/b.piggy-back-on-outgoing-activities):

```js
const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
    if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY') {
    // The channelData submitted here is very similar to HTTP cookies and vulnerable to forgery attack.
    // Make sure you use signature to protect it and verify the signature on the bot side.

    // To minimize unexpected behaviors, we recommend to treat the "action" object as if it is immutable.
    // We use simple-update-in package to update "action" with partial deep cloning.
    action = window.simpleUpdateIn(
        action,
        ['payload', 'activity', 'channelData', 'url'],
        () => window.location.href // This is the part that gets the user's URL
    );
    }
```

A couple of notes:

- This code and sample is for v4 of Web Chat. Your code there uses v3. I recommend using v4; it's very easy to migrate if you don't have a lot of customization.
- The sample is a *little* hard to understand, here's a summary:

---

```js
const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
    if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/POST_ACTIVITY') {
```

This part allows you to edit outgoing activities

---

```js
action = window.simpleUpdateIn(
        action,
        ['payload', 'activity', 'channelData', 'url'],
        () => window.location.href // This is the part that gets the user's URL
    );
```

This part makes the actual edit

---

```js
['payload', 'activity', 'channelData', 'url'],
        () => window.location.href
```

This says you want to set `Activity.ChannelData.Url` to `window.location.href`, which gives the user's current page URL.

---

And, just to show it working:

[image]

[image]

*Note: The send only failed because it hit a breakpoint that I took too long to unpause*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm understanding your question as you have a bot hosted on some website and would like the bot to respond with the url of the page they're on.

You can get that from `ITurnContext.Activity.ServiceUrl` if you're handling it from the ActivityHandler or from `DialogContext.Context.Activity.ServiceUrl` if handling from Dialog.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is incorrect as the `ServiceUrl` is the address of the Bot Service. OP was asking for the Web page address and @mdrichardon's answer would be more accurate.