# How can i get bot web-app URL in Bot Framework Composer?

Tags: azure, botframework, web-chat, bot-framework-composer

I have a bot published on Azure. This bot placed on some web-sites via webchat channel. What i want is to be able to recognize web-sites url.

For example, if my bot is talking to someone on a web site, named [www.test.com](http://www.test.com), i need my bot to tell this person something like "Hello! You are on [www.test.com](http://www.test.com) talking to me".

The closest i could get was using **turn.activity.serviceUrl**, but it gives me "https://webchat.botframework.com/" all the time. Is there any way for me to get actual URL?

Again, i'm using Bot Framework Composer, so i would appreciate any help specifically for Bot Framework Composer.

I am aware of this topic [Get URL of web page from Bot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59827582/get-url-of-web-page-from-bot-framework) , however it doesn't answer my question - solving this in Bot Framework Composer

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be achieved by using Web Chat's `store` and an event activity trigger in Composer.

First, in Web Chat, create an instance of Web Chat's `store` and filter on the `DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED` action type. Within there, send an event that includes the site location hostname. Then, be sure to pass `store` as a property in the `ReactWebChat` component.

Second, in Composer, click the ellipses ('...') for your main dialog and add a trigger. Select 'Activities' from the first drop down, then 'Event received (Event activity)' from the second. Once added, click into the Event received trigger and add 'Send a response'. Lastly, click into the newly created action and add `${turn.activity.value}` to capture and display the value back to the user.

*Note: I'm using the React flavor of Web Chat, but the vanilla version will work just as well.*

**In Web Chat:**

```js
const { createStore, ReactWebChat } = window.WebChat;

const store = window.WebChat.createStore( {}, ( { dispatch } ) => next => async action => {
  if ( action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY' ) {
    console.log( 'ACTIVITY ', action.payload.activity );
  }
  if ( action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED' ) {
    dispatch( {
      type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
      payload: {
        name: 'SEND_HOSTNAME',
        value: `Hello! You are on ${ window.location.hostname } talking to me.`,
      }
    } )
  }

  next( action );
} );

window.ReactDOM.render(
  <ReactWebChat
    directLine={directLine}
    store={store}
  />,
  document.getElementById( 'webchat' )
);
```

**In Composer:**
[image]

**Result:**
[image]

Hope of help!